# Wrong annotation type after JAXB generation

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb

After JAXB generation I have a class that includes wrong type for my int array, it annotates it with Integer type instead of int[].

here is my XSD:

```
<complexType name="GenericChartTask">
    <sequence>
        <element name="clients" type="struct:IDNameSiteServiceImageIndex"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        </element>
        <element name="commonTasks" type="struct:NameAndID"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        </element>
        <element name="groups" type="int" maxOccurs="unbounded"
            minOccurs="0"></element>
        <element name="siteServices" type="struct:SiteService"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        </element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

And here is what I get after generation:

```
public class GenericChartTask {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://american-data.com/ecs/struct")
    protected ad.ecs.struct.IDNameSiteServiceImageIndex[] clients;
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://american-data.com/ecs/struct")
    protected ad.ecs.struct.NameAndID[] commonTasks;
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://american-data.com/ecs/struct", type = Integer.class)
    protected int[] groups;
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://american-data.com/ecs/struct")
    protected ad.ecs.struct.SiteService[] siteServices;
    ...
```

I also have a binding to generate the array instead of the list, since JAXB doesn't want to generate legal bean (it drops setters for lists).

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='groups']">
    <jxb:property collectionType="indexed" />
</jxb:bindings>
```

My question would be, Is there any way to get rid of that faulty part **type = Integer.class**? Because its causing problems when I want to deserialize my JSON for this object.

Answer (score 0):

It is generating as type `Integer` because you have `minOccurs=0` set on it.

Integer is nullable where int is not.

Drop this attribute and it should generate as int.

```
<xs:element name="groups" type="xs:int">
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Ill try this and let you know

Comment: Try drop maxOccurs also

Comment: If I do that it becomes non list field. The whole problem is about lists...